# Is legal/ethical to obtain upload rigths to the Ubuntu archives to fund a support company?

Tags: commercial

I live in Mexico city and in the time I've been involved with Ubuntu I've not seen any local company that offer professional support for Ubuntu.

Is legal/ethical to try to obtain permissions to the Ubuntu archive to provide a better support service?, I have a friend who's trying to obtain upload rights to Debian too.

The idea is that we could provide a more close to Ubuntu/Canonical support for our future customers, however I'm not sure if that would be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ethically there is nothing wrong in your approach; you are simply attempting to be seen as a support partner. As to legality, if you were accepted as a support partner, you would be bound by their terms and conditions and that would therefore also state what permissions you would have (and thus how "legal" your work was.

The ethical and legal implications are essentially moot, what matters is whether Canonical accepts your application. You can find out more here at http://www.ubuntu.com/partners